# Get HTML style like in example image

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'd love to create an element thats looks like this:

[image: img]

This is the code I got so far but Id doesn't seems working like this:

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 22%; left:0%; top: 0%; background: #795547; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #795547; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <div style="color: white; left: 3%; margin-top: 3%; position: fixed; font-size: 11px">TRUE HEADING</div>
        <div style="color: white; display: table; margin:0 auto; margin-top: 3%;  font-size: 11px">MAGNETIC HEADING</div>
        <div style="top: 0%; color: white; right: 3%; margin-top: 3%; position: fixed; font-size: 11px">MAGNETIC FIELD</div>

        <div style="position: fixed; left: 3%; margin-top: 2%; color: white; font-size: 14px">135° SE</div>
        <div style="position: fixed; margin-top: 2%; margin: 0 auto; color: white; font-size: 14px">123° SE</div>
        <div style="position: fixed; right: 2%; margin-top: 2%; color: white; font-size: 14px">49 uT</div>
</div>
```

**How to edit my code to get a result like above?**

Comment: Why are you using position fixed everywhere? You should start from scratch with three blocks and flexbox

Comment: Would you be so kind to please add a small example snippet? @Axnyff

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeQzYq

Comment: @JaneDeverly using position fixed will make the element stuck where it is even when scrolling, so if you add more elements, then it will be in the way of the other elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a another implementation with the flex layout

```css
.container {
display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 background: #795547;
 color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #795547;
}

.flex {
  padding: 2%;
  flex: 1
}

.title , .desc {
 text-align: center
}

.desc {
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="flex">
  <div class="title">TRUE HEADING</div>
  <div class="desc">135° SE</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="title">MAGNETIC HEADING</div>
  <div class="desc">123° SE</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="title">MAGNETIC FIELD</div>
  <div class="desc">49 uT</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank  you for using a style sheet and not inlining all the styles!

Comment: Thanks looks like a nice solution :9

Answer (score 2):

Other approach.

```css
.container{
   position: fixed; 
   width:100%; left:0%; 
   top: 0%; 
   background: #795547; 
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #795547;
}

.detail{
 color: white; 
 display: inline-block; 
 font-size: 25px;
 width: 32%;
}

.header{
   color: white; 
   display: inline-block; 
   font-size: 11px;
   width: 32%;
}

.row{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="header">TRUE HEADING</div>
        <div class="header">MAGNETIC HEADING</div>
        <div class="header">MAGNETIC FIELD</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="detail">135° SE</div>
        <div class="detail">123° SE</div>
        <div class="detail">135° SE</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper{
 position: fixed; 
 width:100%; h
 eight: 22%; 
 left:0%; 
 top: 0%; 
 background: #795547; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #795547; 
 display: table; 
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.column{
 color: white; 
 display:table-cell; 
 font-size: 11px;
    padding:10px;
 text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.column .bigger{
 font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="column">
  TRUE HEADING
  <div class="bigger">135° SE</div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  MAGNETIC HEADING
  <div class="bigger">123° SE</div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  MAGNETIC FIELD
  <div class="bigger">49 uT</div>
 </div>
</div>
```